# Material datepicker filtering

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I'm trying to get the filtering to work. I've modified the [sample](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#input-and-change-events), and can't figure it out why this does not work. I want to disable all days, except the ones in testDates array. "found valid day" is logged out correctly, and yet the days are not selectable.

```
  myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    const testDates: Date[] = [
      new Date('2018-08-30T00:00:00+02:00'),
      new Date('2018-08-28T00:00:00+02:00'),
      new Date('2018-08-21T00:00:00+02:00'),
      new Date('2018-08-23T00:00:00+02:00')
    ]
    testDates.forEach(item => {
      if (item.toDateString() == d.toDateString()) {
        console.debug("found valid day:" + d);
        return true;
      }
    });
    console.debug("invalid day:" + d);
    return false;
  }
```

Here it is in stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6fgvsx?embed=1&file=app/datepicker-filter-example.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use myFilter as the following code:

```
myFilter = (d: Date): boolean => {
    const testDates: Date[] = [
      new Date('2018-08-30T00:00:00+02:00'),
      new Date('2018-08-28T00:00:00+02:00'),
      new Date('2018-08-21T00:00:00+02:00'),
      new Date('2018-08-23T00:00:00+02:00')
    ]

    return testDates.findIndex(testDate => d.toDateString() == testDate.toDateString()) >= 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the return value to a variable, then it will work.

```
let x = false;
testDates.forEach(item => {
    if (item.toDateString() == d.toDateString()) {
        x = true;
    }
})
return x;
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6fgvsx-4yzs4p?file=app%2Fdatepicker-filter-example.ts)